# How can i make my MSI file download from my Website on Button click

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer

I have my Href for downloading MSI and ZIP files directly by clicking on that.  I can download those but when he clicks on that I will have a information where he has to fill the required details. After filling and clicking on Download button he can able to download the required file selected

I write the following but no use

```
        Response.Redirect("/Download/ACHTest.msi");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this create 2 links instaed of one and ry to pass the values as follows on Linkbuttons page

```
protected void lnkMsi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext _context = HttpContext.Current;

    _context.Items.Add("val", "lnkMsi");

    Server.Transfer("downloadInfo.aspx");
}

protected void lnkZip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext _context = HttpContext.Current;

    _context.Items.Add("val", "lnkZip");

    Server.Transfer("downloadInfo.aspx");
}
```

On Download page

```
     if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        HttpContext _context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (_context.Items["val"].ToString() == "lnkMsi")
        {
            DownloadType = "Msi";
            oDownInfo.DownloadType = DownloadType;
        }
        else if (_context.Items["val"].ToString() == "lnkZip")
        {
            DownloadType = "Zip";
            oDownInfo.DownloadType = DownloadType;
        }
        else
        {
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```